# How to pack a 3 dim array/ how to map it on a 1 dim array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, fortran

I have a question concerning the packing of multidimensional arrays. I'm stuck at the moment and maybe somebody can help me out since I think it is a rather trivial task. I'm programing in Fortran, but the language doens't matter here so much.

During my work I have to store informations on triples i,j,k with i <= j <= k, where i,j,k go from 1 to n.

Because the memory demands in my progam are critical, I don't want to waste memory and try to pack the array trip(i,j,k) in an one dimensional array. So far I do it with the pairs ij and map them onto a 1d array (as usual for symmetric matrices) and calculate the index in the 1d array as:

```
ijpair = i*(i+1)/2+j
```

with the maximal number of pairs

```
npair = n*(n+1)/2+n
```

To incorporate the third index I generate n copies of the pair block (for each k). The index for the triple is than:

```
ijktrip = npair*(k-1) + ijpair
```

In this way the memory demands are already reduced, but it is still not optimal and at the moment I can not figure out how to fully exploit the restrictions i <= j <= k.

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already noticed, for a specific `k` you have `k*(k+1)/2` elements. Let's enumerate the elements in increasing order of `k`, then increasing order of `j`, and then increasing order of `i`.

For a given `k` you already used `sum_{1 <= p < k} p*(p+1)/2` indices. This sum evaluates to (see [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%5Bi%28i%2B1%29%2F2%2C%20%7Bi%2C%201%2C%20k-1%7D%5D))

```
k*(k-1)*(k+1)/6
```

In the `k`-plane you need to do a similar thing for `j`: for a given `j` you already used `sum_{1 <= p < j} p = j*(j-1)/2` indices.

On the `jk`-line you repeat this: for a given `i` you already used `i-1` indices.

This yields the total formula:

```
index(i, j, k) = k*(k-1)*(k+1)/6 + j*(j-1)/2 + i
```

---

Note that (again, see [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n*%28n-1%29*%28n%2B1%29%2F6%2Bn*%28n-1%29%2F2%2Bn))

```
index(n, n, n) = n*(n-1)*(n+1)/6 + n*(n-1)/2 + n = n*(n+1)*(n+2)/6
```

which is exactly the number of elements you have, so no indices are wasted.